# convert value to label under angular primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Could you do me a favor?

environment is angular9 and primeng.

I have two pages.

1. show detail.
2. edit/create.

2.has p-dropdown component. this is working fine.

> <p-dropdown name="type" [options]="types" [(ngModel)]="info.type">

1.is problem.  i can display value but not label.
I tried as follow. this is not working.

> {{types[info.type].label}}

List is defined like this.
x.component.ts

> ```
> readonly types: SelectItem[] = [
>     { label: '---', value: null }, //index=0
>     { label: 'a', value: '0' }, //index=1
>     { label: 'b', value: '1' }, //index=2
>     { label: 'c', value: '2' }, //index=3
> ];
> ```

if info.type = 1,
right answer is 'b' but it returned 'a'.

> types[info.type].label // <-this is recognized as index, not value.

How to search list from value?
My image is like this.

> types[value -> info.type].label

or

> types['' + info.type].label

ofcourse these are not work.
I have 350 dropdowns in my page, so if possible, do not want to write convert code in component.ts.

Comment: Could you please show how `info` is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use **optionLabel** in the p-dropdown with the key from json, you want to display.

```html
<p-dropdown  optionLabel="label" name="type" [options]="types" [(ngModel)]="info.type"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  dropdown is working fine.  problem is label (simple text) instead of dropdown.


    <p-dropdown name="type" [options]="types" [(ngModel)]="info.type"> // <- this is working fine.

    {{types[info.type].label}} // <- this is not working

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information you've provided, it seems the `label: '---'` is messing with the array index. Try replacing

```html
{{ types[info.type].label }}
```

with

```html
{{ types[info.type + 1]?.label }}
```

[Safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?.` is also used to verify if `types[info.type - 1]` is defined before trying to access it's property `label`.

Comment: thank you for your response.  it looks like nice idea, but not solve the problem.
because no one can promise the list is unchange for future. For example, 
if the list is changed to:

    readonly types: SelectItem[] = [
        { label: '---', value: null }, //index=0
        { label: 'a', value: '0' }, //index=1
        { label: 'a+', value: '3'}, //index=2
        { label: 'b', value: '1' }, //index=3
        { label: 'c', value: '2' }, //index=4
    ];

data is not much to the list anymore.
so, cannot save the data to database as index.  must save value.

Answer (score 0):

now, i found the solution.
this solution is bit different from my request.
but it is work.

i make new component and add code to it.

component.html

```
 {{ label }}
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listlabel',
  templateUrl: './listlabel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listlabel.component.css']
})
export class ListlabelComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() list: SelectItem[];
    @Input() value: string;   
    public label: string;

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.label = this.list.filter(item => item.value == this.value)[0].label;   
    }
}
```

mother.html

```
<app-listlabel [value]="info.type" [list]="types"></app-listlabel>
```

Thanks everyone!